# Custom Celery task initialisation

Tags: python, celery, celery-task

The docs say that custom tasks are instantiated only once, and that it is a good way to cache needed data like database connections for all task invocations. But it seems it occurs both on the worker, and the caller. A task MCVE:

```
# tasks.py

from celery import Celery, Task
from time import sleep

celery = Celery(
    broker="redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0",
    backend="redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0"
)


class PatternTask(Task):
    def __init__(self):
        print("Initialising task")
        sleep(10)
        self._pattern = "Hello, %s!"
        print("Initialised task")

    @property
    def pattern(self):
        return self._pattern

@celery.task(base=PatternTask)
def hello(who):
    sleep(2)
    return hello.pattern % who
```

and calling code:

```
# main.py

from tasks import hello

print(hello.delay("world").get())
print(hello.delay("you").get())
```

This will delay both the worker and the calling code by 10 seconds:

```
$ python main.py
Initialising task
# <10 seconds>
Initialised task
# <2 seconds>
Hello, world!
# <2 seconds>
Hello, you!
```

I understand this is necessary to support the case of `hello("now")`, where worker is not involved. However, is there a way to promise I will never do so, and avoid the expensive `sleep` operation and the huge waste of time, memory and CPU resources† in allocating `_pattern` in the calling code? If not, what is the recommended solution for this scenario?

---

†) The actual use case is loading gigabytes of data needed for worker's operation, that the calling code will have no use for.

Comment: Well of course the caller also has to instantiate the object. Did you try performing the expensive operation outside of the init, with something like a @property (or even better, a cached_property)?

Comment: @MichelKok As usual, the ideas come immediately after I post! :D I already started experimenting with `@functools.cached_property`, and it is close — the one downside is that it will perform the initialisation on first task. This led me to discovering `@celery.signals.worker_ready.connect` (or `worker_init`?), and I'm looking to see if that solves it. Thank you for the comment!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was: Celery signals.

```
# tasks.py

from celery import Celery, Task, signals
from time import sleep

celery = Celery(
    broker="redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0",
    backend="redis://127.0.0.1:6379/0"
)


class PatternTask(Task):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        signals.worker_init.connect(self.on_worker_init)

    def on_worker_init(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("Initialising task")
        sleep(10)
        self._pattern = "Hello, %s!"
        print("Initialised task")

    @property
    def pattern(self):
        return self._pattern

@celery.task(bind=True, base=PatternTask)
def hello(self, who):
    print(f"In hello {who}")
    sleep(2)
    print(f"Done hello {who}")
    return self.pattern % who
```

The worker will apparently not start accepting jobs until the `celery.signals.worker_init` handlers are all done. (I also used `bind=True` to make it more maintainable; this is not relevant to the solution.)